# Wordpress, excerpts and Image Links

Tags: wordpress

*Quickinfo:*

1. I am using wordpress 3.5.1 with the latest version of the "FancyBox
   for WordPress" -Plugin.
2. I use the more-Tag for all articles, making
   only excerpts of them beeing shown on the start-page.

*Facts:*

1. In wordpress image-thumbnails included in the article are enclosed
   in a link pointing to the image-url by default.
2. The Fancybox-Plugin makes such Links open the image in a jQuery Fancybox.

*My Problem:*

Sometimes I show images in the excerpts, too.

At this time theres happening an usability-flaw:

When clicking on the Image a fancybox will open, but people expect to get redirected to the full article instead.

Is anyone aware of a solution how to overcome this issue, maybee by using an other plugin, changing the structure of my articles or editing some php-files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the plugin you are using but I've always used colorbox. There's a plugin for it designed for wordpress and it allows you to specify which images you want to open in a jquery window.